# RxJS: How should I update elements in observable via socket.js event?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

Was trying to reimplement main application of the company switching from Promises and imperative style to RxJS and functional style. And found myself in a specific situation.

**Problem:** We have a list of posts in the system that can be filtered.
So, I have created a pretty straightforward filter component and a list component where I receive data like this:

```
this.items = this.filterChange
    .startWith(this.filterComponent.initialValue);
    .debounceTime(400)
    .switchMap((data) => this.process(data))
    .share();
```

But then I need to plug in another event from sockets which updates individual elements in the list. Our `process` function can understand both events and react on them, but the issue is:

```
merge(this.filterChange.debounceTime(400), this.socketUpdates)
    .startWith(this.filterComponent.initialValue);
    .switchMap((data) => this.process(data))
    .share();
```

if update happens right after search was changed we lose search changes result, what should I do in this situation?

*PS:* I have considered as an option `combineLatest` + `pariwise` to have an ability what was changed and react on that. Isn't there more elegant solution?

Comment: Why are the two streams merged? `this.filterChange` is a search filter and `this.socketUpdates` sends what? Both are processed with `.switchMap((data) => this.process(data))` so how you lose search results?

Comment: Cause I wan in tempalte to have a single source of data. So I should not worry about where my data comes from. That's why my streams are merged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a common mistake with RxJS, you're using `switchMap` when you should be using `concatMap` (or maybe `mergeMap`).

`switchMap` is only really safe with non-sideeffectful read-only requests/messages. If you're' trying to update record over the network, and you care about the order in which it's done and results are processed, you want to use `concatMap`. If you don't care about the ordering of results, you should use `mergeMap`.

- `switchMap` - will unsubscribe from any pending Observable when it gets a new value, thus dropping its responses.
- `mergeMap` - will start and run all Observables it creates immediately and to completion, without any care for the order in which results come back as they're merged in.
- `concatMap` - only run one Observable at a time, in order, and drop nothing.

```js
merge(this.filterChange.debounceTime(400), this.socketUpdates)
    .startWith(this.filterComponent.initialValue);
    .concatMap((data) => this.process(data))
    .share();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the desired behavior is to prevent any update from the socket until the search input has been debounced, then you should make one stream dependent on the other, rather than merging. This may be an approach that works for your use case:

```
this.filterChange.switchMap( data => {
    return Observable.of( data )
           .debounceTime( 400 )
           .concat( this.socketUpdates );
  })
  .startWith(this.filterComponent.initialValue);
  .switchMap((data) => this.process(data))
  .share();
```

I don't know exactly what your use case for the `debounceTime` operator is, if you're debouncing the text input or some other data, but you should be able to move it out of the `switchMap` if you like. It's possible that this implementation above will be really "chatty" with subscriptions to the socketUpdates stream, and that may also have consequences for you.

```
this.filterChange.debounceTime( 400 ).switchMap( data => {
    return Observable.of( data ).concat( this.socketUpdates );
  })
  .startWith(this.filterComponent.initialValue);
  .switchMap((data) => this.process(data))
  .share();
```